# Can you check if two objects instances are same

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a LinkedList Class defined here, I wanted to check if you can check  self.head == node or you need to compare the node with all the attributes and define a **equals** method explicitly? I saw code where someone was using this without **equals** method

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self,key=None,value=None):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
        self.previous = None
        self.next = None

class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.count = 0

    def prepend(self,value):
        node = Node(value)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = node
            self.tail = self.head
            self.count = 1
            return

        self.head.previous = node
        node.next = self.head
        self.head = node
        self.count += 1
```

Comment: by default, `==` will use the `object.__eq__` if you haven't defined one, which will compare *equality by identity*, which is not what you want. Why don't you just define what you need?

Answer (score 1):

To see if the address of `obj1` matches the address of `obj2`, use the `is` operator.

You are doing that already in this test:

```
        if self.head is None:
```

There is exactly one object (a singleton) in the `NoneType` class,
and you are essentially asking if `id(self.head)` matches the `id()`, or address, of `None`.

Feel free to do that with other linked list node objects.

If, OTOH, you were to ask if `self.head == some_node`,
that might well be asking if node attribute `a` matches in both,
and attribute `b` matches in both,
depending on your class methods,
e.g. using `def __eq__`.
A node created by a shallow copy might be `==` equal to original,
but `is` will reveal that separate storage is allocated for it.